# How to use NDIS protocol driver?

Tags: windows-ce, driver, ndis

I write a NDIS protocol driver. I can register my protocol with NdisRegisterProtocol.

How does the application typically access this driver? 
Is there a way to uses windows sockets or do I need to provide a StreamDriver interface?

The socket function has a third parameter 'protocol' that usually something like IPPROTO_UDP. Can I select my protocol driver using this parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocol drivers aren't automatically exposed in the Windows Sockets API (and this is a good thing, since it gives you the most architectural flexibility).  But you can get it to work by implementing a couple extra pieces.

1. You need to implement some channel to communicate with your driver. I'm not too familiar with Windows CE, but StreamDriver sounds like a plausible way to do that.
2. You need to expose that channel through Winsock. Write a "Transport Service Provider" library that takes requests from Winsock and translates them into something your protocol driver can understand.

This is how TCPIP (the protocol driver) shows up as IPPROTO_UDP (the Winsock protocol type) — the OS includes a TSP for TCP, UDP, and Raw IP.

The CE-specific documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee495130%28v=WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx), but the [NT documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740576%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is worth reading too for the overview section.